# Have two domains point to the same content on a wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I have a Wordpress Multisite installation with several domains and subdomains on it.

Everything works fine.

Now I'd like to add a **new domain name** I just bought, **pointing to the same content as one of the existing domains** on the Multisite.

(Incidentally, it's the "main" site on the network, which also serves as a Network manager).

(no I'm not concerned with SEO problems).

To this end, I have done two things:

1. created an Alias server pointing to the domain I want to replicate (via Virtualmin). (**This works very well outside of Wordpress**.)
2. added the new domain as one of the multisites on Wordpress.

The result of the above is that the new domain isn't treated as an alias at all, but as a new website whose content needs to be filled in.

Now, get this: If I only do point 1) above, **Wordpress acts as if I am trying to sign in a new website onto the multisite**, and takes me to the registration page (even though, registration is disabled).

(Unfortunately I cannot go back to having multiple single sites now...)

I hope I managed to explain the situation clearly. I feel like I should draw a picture!

Is there any good way out of this? Perhaps get Wordpress to disregard the auto-registration thing?

Comment: You just need to get WordPress to recognise the second domain as belonging to the same blog as the first one. I don't know what the modern way of doing this is: it might be possible to set it up as an alias, or you can write code in wp-config.php or sunrise.php to map this manually, setting `global $blog_id`. You probably then need to override blog_url and site_url too so that it doesn't try and redirect to the other URL.

Comment: Or maybe it was $current_blog and $current_site. Sorry, I'm out-of-date and rusty. https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.1.1/wp-includes/ms-settings.php#L53

Comment: I wish your input was sufficient to put me on the right track, but sadly I need more details. I am not sure what you are suggesting I should try to do.

Comment: OK, I’ll try and have a more detailed look later